# как привязать datatable к combobox в XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Д0бр0го времени суток.
Есть код:

```
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cb" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=datatable1}" IsTextEditable="False" ValueMember="ID" DisplayMember="NAME" EditValueChanged="cb_EditValueChanged"/>
```

Событие cb_EditValueChanged сохраняет выбранный ID в таблице datatable2. Как мне сделать так что бы из datatable1 выбиралась строка у которой id равно datatable2.Rows[0][id] ?

Comment: В ItemsSource="{Binding Path=datatable1}" - в datatable1 много строк а нужна та у которой id = datatable2.Rows[0][id]

Comment: Возможно вам нужен `MultiBinding` и конвертер `IMultiValueConverter`, либо свойство, которое возвращает нужное значение в геттере, и привязать к нему `SelectedIndex`.

Comment: Всё так сложно? В WinForms просто можно было указать SelectedValue

Comment: Ну здесь есть аналог `SelectedItem` тогда, который содержит в себе выбранный элемент, и `SelectedIndex`, который содержит индекс этого элемениа в привязанной коллекции. И то и другое можно прибиндить к свойству.